# Azure auto tag resource groups

Tags: azure

Hi I have been looking around for a way to automatically tag resource groups when they are created on our azure subscription but I have had no look in finding a way to do it I have seen there is a way you can use an Azure function to do it from here https://github.com/itaysk/azure-tagowner/blob/master/azure-function/tag-owner/index.js but I am not sure how to exactly implement it any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy can be used to achieve what you are trying to do.

There is a [built-in policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#tags) called "Add a tag to resource groups", which can be used to add a set tag to a resource group when it is created or updated.

If you want something more dynamic then you would need to look for something else.